# Create a new table based on existing table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to write a query in Access 2003 that creates a new table based on the existing one. 
I'm using a Make Table Query.

Before:

```
NAME  A_1   A_2  B_1    B_2
X      1    2    3      4
Y      5    6    7      8
```

AFTER

```
NAME    Section Value1  Value2  
X          A    1        2  
X          B    3        4  
Y          A    5        6  
Y          B    7        8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `SELECT` query which retrieves the *A_1* and *A_2* values from each row of your existing table:

```sql
SELECT e1.NAME, 'A' AS [Section], e1.A_1 AS Value1, e1.A_2 AS Value2
FROM tblExisting AS e1
```

Then create a similar query which retrieves the *B_1* and *B_2* values, and `UNION` the two `SELECT` statements:

```sql
SELECT e1.NAME, 'A' AS [Section], e1.A_1 AS Value1, e1.A_2 AS Value2
FROM tblExisting AS e1
UNION ALL
SELECT e2.NAME, 'B' AS [Section], e2.B_1 AS Value1, e2.B_2 AS Value2
FROM tblExisting AS e2
```

From there, you can build a make table query based on the `UNION` query:

```sql
SELECT sub.*
    INTO tblNew
FROM
    (
        SELECT e1.NAME, 'A' AS [Section], e1.A_1 AS Value1, e1.A_2 AS Value2
        FROM tblExisting AS e1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT e2.NAME, 'B' AS [Section], e2.B_1 AS Value1, e2.B_2 AS Value2
        FROM tblExisting AS e2
    ) AS sub;
```